# Can one installation of karma be configured to run both jasmine 1.3 and 2.0 tests?

Tags: jasmine, teamcity, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have a TeamCity CI server that needs to be able to execute Jasmine 1.3 and Jasmine 2.0 tests (at different times, on different jobs).  It is using the TeamCity Karma integration.  My research so far is inconclusive, but it seems like Karma can only have one version of the Jasmine plugin at a time, so it's an either-or proposition.  Another way to attack it would be to have two separate installs of Karma on the TeamCity server, but I'm a newbie at both TeamCity and Node, and not sure how this would work out.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karma looks for the `karma-jasmine` plugin in the local `node_modules` folder. The quickest way to switch versions is to simply replace the `karma-jasmine` folder with the version you want (automated or otherwise) before running your tests, but this has the potential to get messy.

Different installs of Karma is likely the cleaner way. There isn't any issue with having 2 (or as many as you like) *local* installs of Karma, since they all live under a `node_modules` folder. In an example directory structure like this, the Karma installation under 1.3 won't know anything about the Karma installation under 2.0.

```
/tests/
    /1.3/
        /node_modules/
            /karma/
            /karma-jasmine/
    /2.0/
        /node_modules/
            /karma/
            /karma-jasmine/
```

`karma-cli`, the module that lets you run `karma` in a command window from anywhere, however, is one that is installed *globally* and so has one installation.

If you ran `karma start` while in the 1.3 folder, `karma-cli` will execute the Karma under 1.3, which in turn will load the `karma-jasmine` under 1.3. The same applies when in the 2.0 folder. This gives you the option of maintaining versioned test dependencies.

Comment: Thanks,  that's what I suspected,  but good to have the details